# ClamAV copy checked non infected files

Tags: bash, raspbian, clam

I´m currently writing a script that checks USB Sticks for malicious files that runs on a Raspberry Pi.

For AV Checking I´m using `clamscan` like this:

```
clamscan --infected --allmatch --detect-pua --block-macros --recursive --block-encrypted $start_directory
```

where $start_directory is the mount point of the USB-Drive.

clamscan has a `--move` option for infected files. But how can I automatically copy files that clamscan tests as OK to a desired directory?

Comment: Does the "$start_directory" contain only files?

Comment: it contains files and folders of unknown format, thats why i used the **--recursive** option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a negate option `clamscan` so you could
do something like

```
declare -a infectedlist=( $(clamscan --infected --allmatch --detect-pua --block-macros --recursive --block-encrypted "$start_directory") )
shopt -s globstar
for i in "$start_directory"/**
do
[[ ! -f "$i" ]] && continue # If not a file then next item !!
 found=0
 for j in "${infectedlist[@]}"
 do
  [[ "$i" = "$j" ]] && found=1
 done
 [ "$found" -eq 0 ] && mv "$i" /desired/directory
done
shopt -u globstar #unset globstar
```

---

<sup>As a sidenote doublequote the variables ie do `"$start_directory" to avoid word splitting.`</sup>

Comment: @MartinFischer : Added `[[ ! -f "$i" ]] && continue` to skip some unwanted processing.